# Sort posts in order of latest commented post first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

I've following models

Post:

```
has_many :comments
```

Comment:

```
belongs_to :post
```

and a controller called `pages` with following code in it.

```
def home
    @posts = Post.includes(:comments)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
    end
end
```

So say if I've 3 posts P1, P2, P3; initially rendered in same order on `home` page. Later if P2 gets commented and I refresh the page the order should be P2, P1, P3. So whenever a post gets commented it should appear on top. All the posts should be sorted in descending order of time they get commented. How can I achieve this?

My attempt - What I tried is very inefficient and definitely not a good practice. I get unique post_ids from comments in descending order and using the post_ids get the posts.

I'm sure rails provides best way to do it. Help highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
@posts = Post.includes(:comments).order("comments.created_at desc")
```